# Parse error on c# on ul li tags

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a dropdown for login in with this code:

```
<ul>
<li class="mega-menu mega-menu-custom reserved2">
        <a href="/main/login">Access</a>
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { 
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Login</a>
                <ul>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Main", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <li><a class="custom-a-menu">Email</a></li>
                        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Email, null, new { @class = "custom-input" })</li>
                        <li><a class="custom-a-menu">Password</a></li>
                        <li>@Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password, new { @class = "custom-input" })</li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="custom-a-menu">¿Forgot password?</a></li>
                        <li><button type="submit" class="button primary custom-btn">Iniciar</button></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Registrarse</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="custom-a-menu">¿Interested in our services?</a></li></br>
                    <li><a href="/main/register" class="button green custom-btn2">¡Register Now!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
        }
    </li>
</ul>
```

But when it always gives me a parse error on the ul end thag behind the }

I'm trying to hide the register and the login form when the user is authenticated, but I haven't yet added the else part, I'm stuck at this point.

the error is:

Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "ul" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: which "}" ? you've more than one there.

Comment: Try the first "{" on a newline by itself similar to your using? Mebbeh

Comment: also, @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) should probably be 
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated), since you want the login section to show when the user isn't authenticated.

Comment: In addition to what @user1666620 asked, what is the actual error message you are receiving?

Comment: @user1666620 I have 2 because I'm using the BeginForm inside the IsAuthenticated. It's the last one.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung this is the error: Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "ul" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Comment: You also have multiple HTML errors - there is no such thing as </br>. And you cannot put `Html.BeginForm` inside the `<ul>` A form element is not a valid child of a ul.

Comment: I'm not sure <form> can be a descendant of <ul> ?

Comment: @tschmit007 it can be a descendant of <ul>, but it cannot be a direct child of a <ul>

Comment: @CharlesBoyung I don't really know what fixed it, I just changed the </br> to <br /> and the error disappeared :l

Comment: </br> is not a valid HTML element. That's why the error went away. .Net does not like invalid HTML. You technically shouldn't use <br/> anymore either - the valid HTML5 element is just <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this error is the `</br>` at the end of this line:

`<li><a class="custom-a-menu">¿Interested in our services?</a></li></br>`\

If you remove that, the error will go away. You'll still have invalid HTML until you fix the @using location, like Rui's answer shows, but the error will no longer happen.

.Net (and especially MVC in .Net) does not like invalid HTML. Invalid HTML will cause all sorts of problems with the view rendering engine, such as this.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there will generate markup that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <form>
        <li>email:</li>
        ...
    </form>
</ul>
```

The form is the first child of ul and the children of ul should be li's.

Put the ul inside of `@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Main", FormMethod.Post))`, i.e.:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Main", FormMethod.Post)){
   <ul>
      <li>...
```

Also, as others have pointed out you have a `</br>` in your code. It should be `<br/>`

Comment: While correct, this does not answer the question or resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The direct issue here is the line break  just after "Interested in our services", change

```
</br>
```

to

```
<br/>
```

and your code will compile, but there are other issues as others have pointed out.

Comment: thanks! That did it. I've fixed a few things the others pointed out, you guys are awesome. Thanks for all the quick answers!

Answer (score 1):

When I post this code into VS, I get an error on `</br>`... it doesn't like that syntax (and it's not valid HTML anyway).  Use `<br/>` instead.

In addition, I am not sure why that `</br>` is there in the first place...  `<li>` elements are block level.  Use CSS styling to create gaps, not `<br>`.